# sbt scripted plugin fails as an unresolved dependency on publishing cross-compiled scala versions

Tags: scala, sbt, dependency-management, playframework-2.6, scala-version-cross-build

Our [`play-googleauth`](https://github.com/guardian/play-googleauth) library is built on Scala 2.12, and cross-compiled to Scala 2.11, using sbt 1.1.6. As the library is intended to be run in Play projects, we've historically provided an example standalone Playframework project that uses the library, so that users can see how to set it up.

I recently added the sbt plugin [`scripted`](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Testing-sbt-plugins.html) to the project, so that by running the sbt command `scripted` we could check the example project works correctly. However, I now find that our release process fails:

```
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.scala-sbt#scripted-sbt_2.11;1.1.6: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]      org.scala-sbt:scripted-sbt_2.11:1.1.6 ((sbt.ScriptedPlugin.projectSettings) ScriptedPlugin.scala#L43)
[warn]        +- com.gu:play-googleauth_2.11:0.7.7-SNAPSHOT
```

If you clone the repo and checkout the [`scripted-plugin-fails-to-resolve`](https://github.com/guardian/play-googleauth/tree/scripted-plugin-fails-to-resolve) tag you can reproduce this by running `sbt +publishLocal`.

What's going wrong here? Is the problem that `scripted` is intended for development of sbt plugins rather that Scala libraries (if so, is there a good alternative)? I know that `scripted` is used in Play 2.6, which cross compiles to both Scala 2.12 & 2.11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Maven Central](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scala-sbt/scripted-plugin_2.11) indicates scripted-plugin 1.1.6 is not published for 2.11.

Play 2.6 uses [SBT 0.13.17](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/7dd7938fe3b2a27cdf18d612a33fd02b20b69595/framework/project/build.properties) and so fetches [scripted-plugin 0.13.17](https://dl.bintray.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/scripted-plugin/0.13.17/)

Comment: Ha! I'm still pretty confused by what numbering scheme `scripted-plugin` uses... has it transitioned from being published on dl.bintray.com/typesafe to Maven Central? In any case, I think you're right, thanks for figuring that out! I guess I'll give up use of  `scripted-plugin`.